# Rails routing for multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use one rails application to serve multiple sites.

Sites have approximately the same functionality, but I have different url paths.

Is it possible to register different routes for different domains in rails?

Now my application is on php and I connected routing like this

```
if ($domain == 'domain1.com') {
    include_once 'domain1.com_router.php';
} elseif ($domain == 'domain2.com') {
    include_once 'domain2.com_router.php';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use constraint blocks for this

```
constraints domain: 'domain1.com' do
  ...
end

constraints domain: 'domain2.com' do
  ...
end
```

You can also apply constraints to individual routes like so

```
root :to => "static#home", :constraints => { :domain => "domain1.com" }
```

Comment: and what for local dev env?

Comment: I guess you could test it by editing your system host files (search how to do it on your os), to add something like `127.0.0.1 domain1.com` => domain1.com will then resolve to localhost